# Ignore child order while comparing the xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have two xml document such as:

```
aDoc.xml:
 <update id="1293">
    <abc>.....</abc>
    <xyz>....</xyz>
    <components>
      <component name="C1">
        <files source="s1" target="t1">
          <file>**file2**</file>
          <file>**file1**</file>
        </files>
      </component>
    </components>
  </update>



bDoc.xml:
 <update id="1293">
   <abc>.....</abc>
    <xyz>....</xyz>
    <components>
      <component name="C1">
        <files source="s1" target="t1">
          <file>**file1**</file>
          <file>**file2**</file>
        </files>
      </component>
   </components>
  </update>
```

what i have tried so far is:

```
var DiffInA = aDoc.Descendants("component").Cast<XNode>().Except(bDoc.Descendants("component").Cast<XNode>(), new XNodeEqualityComparer());
```

the above line returns the output as below:

```
 <component name="C1">
        <files source="s1" target="t1">
          <file>file2</file>
          <file>file1</file>
        </files>
```

**(the node which is present in aDoc but not part of bDoc)**

But if you look at **both the xml files the component C1 is same only the order in which the  tag appears is different.**

**Is there any way to achieve this using linq to xml.(i dont want to use XmlDiff or other Api's.)**

Comment: Add an OrderBy to sort by content.

Comment: I am trying to sort the content with aDoc.Descendants("component").OrderBy(x => x.Descendants("file")) but its not working upon running the code.